# How to query historical table size of database in Redshift to determine database size growth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to project forward the size of my Amazon Redshift tables because I'm planning to expand my Redshift cluster size.

I know how to query the table size for today (see query below) but how can I measure the growth of my table sizes over time without make an ETL job to make snapshot day-by-day table size?

```
-- Capture table sizes
select
    trim(pgdb.datname) as Database,
    trim(pgn.nspname) as Schema,
    trim(a.name) as Table,
    b.mbytes,
    a.rows
from (
    select db_id, id, name, sum(rows) as rows
    from stv_tbl_perm a
    group by db_id, id, name
) as a
join pg_class as pgc on pgc.oid = a.id
join pg_namespace as pgn on pgn.oid = pgc.relnamespace
join pg_database as pgdb on pgdb.oid = a.db_id
join (
    select tbl, count(*) as mbytes
    from stv_blocklist
    group by tbl
) b on a.id = b.tbl
order by mbytes desc, a.db_id, a.name;
```

Comment: What do you mean by usage size? Please Edit your question and provide details of how you are getting "usage size just today", so that we can see what information you are seeking.

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein,  
I have edited my question sir, hope you and anyone understand what i mean and can help me :) thanks

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I now understand it a lot better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no historical table size information retained by Amazon Redshift. You would need to run a query on a regular basis, such as the one in your question.

You could wrap the query in an `INSERT` statement and run it on a weekly basis, inserting the results into a table. This way, you'll have historical table size information for each table each week that you can use to predict future growth.

It would be worth doing a `VACUUM` prior to such measurements, to remove deleted rows from storage.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. John for your answer and your editing, now I can focus on making an ETL job for capture daily table size :D , hope this answer will help other too

Comment: Hi @MaulanaMalikIbrahim, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Following metrics is available in cloudwatch

- RedshiftManagedStorageTotalCapacity (m1)
- PercentageDiskSpaceUsed (m2).

[Create a cloudwatch math expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) m1*m2/100 to get this data for the past 3 months.